# EF HasOptional WithMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-entity-framework

Im having a problem that i just cant solve by google or searching on stackoverflow.

i have two tables JournalLines and Accounts and i want to reference a account in a journalline (i hate economics) but the reference has to be optional and Account shoulnt have any navigation property to the JournalLine (ideally).

**JournalLine:**

```
public class JournalLine : Entity<int>
{
    public int? Account_Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }
    public decimal Debit { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

**_Account:**

```
public class Account : Entity<int>
{
    public string Accid { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int VatcodeId { get; set; }
}
```

**And the respective mappings:**

```
public class JournalLineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<JournalLine>
{
    public JournalLineMap()
    {
        HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.Account_Id });
        Property(k => k.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        
        ToTable("attJournalLines");
        HasEntitySetName("JournalLines");
        
        HasOptional(jl => jl.Account)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(jl => jl.Account_Id);
    }
}

public class AccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        ToTable("attAccounts");
        HasEntitySetName("Accounts");
    }
}
```

The error im getting is like:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential >constraint in Role 'JournalLine_Account_Target' in relationship 'JournalLine_Account'. >Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the >Principal Role must be '1'.

This confuses me and i hope some one can shed som light on the problem.

## Update

Thanks for the answers it helped me on the way and i got the relation to work by removing the key. Then i got a wierd behavoir when assigning an `Account` to a `JournalLine` a duplicate account was created. As it turns out this isnt such weird behaviour since im using a Repository pattern with dependency injection. What i didnt think of was that the context wasnt the same in both repositories so the JournalLinesRepository wasnt tracking the account i fetched from its own repository and therefor thought it smart to just insert it as new entity. This was solved by injecting the same context in the repositories so the item tracking works as expected. Again thankyou for your help.

Comment: What is `Entity<int>`?  Perhaps I'm out of date on EF--is it a part of the framework, or is it a custom base-class where <T> is the Id property?

Comment: That is correct its just a custom baseclass that specifies what type the Id column has. A bit redundant in some cases but useful in other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ohlin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467001/60724) correctly identifies the issue--you cannot have a compound primary key with a nullable column.  This raises some questions about what you're trying to model.

Aside from the primary key it appears that your model would work.  In fact I think just removing `HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.Account_Id });` will make things work.  If you do that then every `JournalLine` will have it's own unique ID, and optionally relate to an `Account`.

This would result in data such as:

```
| AccountId | Desc         |
| 123456789 | Some Account |

| JournalId | AccountId | Description | Credit | Debit |
|         1 |      null |     Some Tx | 100.00 |   0.0 |
|         2 | 123456789 |  Another Tx |    0.0 |  50.0 |
|         3 | 123456789 |      MoreTx |  10.00 |   0.0 |
```

On the other hand, if your reason for having an `AccountId` in your `JournalLine` key is to imply that each account effectively has its own Journal (which sounds vaguely familiar from my Account classes) then your modeling needs some tweaking--or you possibly need a special "uncategorized" account specifically to handle transactions that aren't applied to a specific account.

Comment: This almost works as intended except for getting duplicate lines in the Account table of the account i add to a line.

Comment: To create new JournalLines for an existing Account you should retrieve the account first (somethign like `context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(acct => acct.Id == someAccountId)`).

Comment: Thats how im doing it. But when i save the it creates a new Account in the table any idea why?

Comment: I could hypothesize, but it would be best if you open a new question with a concise example

Answer (score 3):

By looking at your code it "feels" like `HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.Account_Id });` can be causing the problem since `Account_Id` is nullable and that's usually not accepted as a key. Try to remove the nullable flag for Account_Id just to see what happens.

**Edit: Keys in EF**

A key always needs to be unique in it's combination (if you have several columns and keys). That's the basic rule behind why you can't allow null values for key parameters.

You're already adding a key for Account_Id when you specify it as a foreign key further down so why do you want it as a primary key as well? Especially since you allow it to be null?

Comment: I believe this is correct; it would be helpful to have a better understanding of the intended relationships.  If JournalLines are occasionally keyed by account then it implies the account is the parent

Comment: I've added a little to my question but basically I don't understand why you want Account_Id as primary key. And you have no reference from Account to JournalLines so they can't be keyed from account.

Comment: Perhaps the intent is to effectively have a Journal-Per-Account, which is how many Accounting ledgers are laid out (if I recall)

Comment: Thank for the answer removed the Account_Id as a key and altogheter in the Mappings and replaced HasForeginKey with Map(m=>m.MapKey("Account_Id")) and that sort of works. But when adding an account to a line and updating the line somehow it creates another account. Im gonna look over the code and make some more tests.

Comment: @STW Yes, a Journal-Per-Account was what I thought as well but if AccountId can be null then you might end up with Account orphans that doesn't belong to any Journal and that's something I didn't understand the purpose of.

Comment: @Patrik I'm glad you found your solution

Comment: @Ohlin yes but orphan accounts arent the trouble since Accounts are actually synced from our buisness system and just used to look vatcodes rates and what have you.